# Union All - Union None? Find non-duplicates only?

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, union

I have two sources of data. One local copy, and one copy uploaded to a server. I wanted to check that no data had been corrupted and so I downloaded the servers copy and stuck them both in MS Access.

Both tables show as having 1200000 rows, this is a good start, however what about the actual data within those rows. I decided a union would work it out. If both tables are identical then there should be no duplicates and therefore the union will also only have 1200000 rows.

```
SELECT tbl1.* FROM [local table] tbl1
UNION
SELECT tbl2.* FROM [server table] tbl2;
```

Unfortunately this returned 1203005 rows which suggests there are 3005 rows which are not identical in both tables. Now `UNION ALL` would return all rows with regardless of duplicates, in this case 2400000 rows.

Is there a `UNION NONE` which would return only the entries which are different in both tables?

Kind regards,

Comment: Do you have an unique key for the rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [all important fields here, maybe all] FROM
    (
    SELECT ...
    UNION
    SELECT ...
    ) AS temp
GROUP BY [all important fields here, maybe all] HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Or do a FULL JOIN like the following

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 AS t1
FULL JOIN tbl2 AS t2 ON t1.firstColumn = t2.firstColumn AND t2.second ...
WHERE t1.firstColumn IS NULL OR t2.firstColumn IS NULL
```

But then the answer wont be exactly what you want since you will get all the columns, both from tbl1 and tbl2

Comment: Access does not support FULL JOIN !

Comment: Didn't realize that, however you can simulate a "FULL OUTER JOIN" with three queries which you union together. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm

Comment: Of course you can "simulate" the FULL Outer join @Sasse. However given the dataset, I would imagine it would be inefficient procedure over Subqueries. Which is what the article in my answer highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried any of the methods in the Microsoft KB article? [Compare Two tables and Find records without matches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-HA010205132.aspx)?

It highlights the use of the Query Designer to make the Query as simple as possible. Have a look at it.